# Delete large amount of records in chunk from a Table using SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I have a table which contains more than 5 million records
I need to delete 300000 of records but I can not use composite key of the table.
Have to use column `Price_VERSION_SEQ` for deleting. I was thinking to delete data in chunks using fetch first 50000 rows only in inner query. But I am not sure what to use in Where clause of main query.

Please help.what should be used to replace ****.

```
DELETE FROM Price_TBL where **** in 
(Select * from Price_TBL where Price_VERSION_SEQ=1 fetch first 50000 rows only);
```

**Columns present in Tables are :**

```
Price_GRP_VAR_COD
Price_VERSION_SEQ
Price_MP_OPER_COD
Price_FROM_MPM_RT
Price_FROM_MPM_RT1
```

**Composite key** :

```
Price_GRP_VAR_COD
Price_VERSION_SEQ
Price_MP_OPER_COD
```

Comment: I am not convinced that dividing the delete is the best way to solve your problem, but maybe you have good reasons for doing so. Did you try deleting everything in one go? If it failed due to some memory setting, is the required reconfiguration unfeasible? Just some food for thought.

Comment: I am getting time out error , as resource allocated to me are limited.
And it can not be increased.
So the only option left for me is to divide the query and avoid time out.

Comment: Is Price_VERSION_SEQ indexed? If it is, use that column, otherwise chose another indexed column. BTW. Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? (Does any of them support the FETCH FIRST syntax?!?) Un-tag product not involved.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `****` with all columns in order. I simpler way would be to just select the key:

```
DELETE FROM Price_TBL where (Price_GRP_VAR_COD, Price_VERSION_SEQ, Price_MP_OPER_COD) in 
(Select Price_GRP_VAR_COD, Price_VERSION_SEQ, Price_MP_OPER_COD from Price_TBL where Price_VERSION_SEQ=1 fetch first 50000 rows only);
```

Comment: Can we use more than one parameter separated by "," ?
I do not think that above query is correct syntax wise.

Comment: Forgot the parenthesis around `Price_GRP_VAR_COD, Price_VERSION_SEQ, Price_MP_OPER_COD`. Try the updated statement. Oh, I'm not at all sure about syntax of the subselect. Since you didn't ask about that I assumed it works on your database manager.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the relevant column `Price_VERSION_SEQ`.

```
DELETE FROM Price_TBL 
WHERE Price_VERSION_SEQ IN
(
    SELECT Price_VERSION_SEQ
    FROM Price_TBL
    WHERE Price_VERSION_SEQ=1
    FETCH FIRST 50000 ROWS ONLY
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-select to find the 50000:th Price_VERSION_SEQ value. Use that value in the `DELETE`'s `WHERE` clause.

```
DELETE FROM Price_TBL
   where Price_VERSION_SEQ <= (Select Price_VERSION_SEQ from Price_TBL
                               order by Price_VERSION_SEQ
                               offset 50000 fetch first 1 rows only);
```

Untested, don't know if it works with MySQL and/or SQL Server, but at least it's ANSI SQL.

BTW, I think MySQL has `LIMIT 50000,1`, and SQL Server has `SELECT TOP` something, if the `OFFSET`/`FETCH FIRST` syntax doesn't work.